# How can I use a linq2sql database on wp7 mango, while maintaining blendability?

Tags: sql-server-ce, mvvm-light, design-time, sql-server-ce-3.5, blendability

I'm trying to create a WP7 application using MVVM Light and SQL Server CE as a database. To accomplish this I generated a datacontext using sqlmetal.exe (1).

This works ok if I run the application on my phone. But when trying to display design time data, I can't create an instance of the `DataContext` in my design time code. Can this be done? Another way I tried was to create an instance of `Table<MyDataObject>`, but System.Data.Linq.Table has no constructors.

So my question is if it is possible to somehow create an instance of my `DataContext` from code or that there is another way to interface with my database without loosing design time data.

(1) Actually I used a different method using a library project to be able to visually design and copied the designer file to my WP7 project. The result in the same if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many failed attempts I couldn't work out a way to programmatically mock the `DataContext` object. So I did it in a different way solving my problem.

I created a service interface to query the data from the database. For every table in the SQL CE database I had to manually create a function.

```
public interface IPayDataService {
    IQueryable<Account> GetAccounts();
    IQueryable<User> GetUsers();
    IQueryable<PayEntry> GetEntries();
}
```

In the real data object the corresponding tables are passed. In the design time object I create the objects in code and return the `IQueryable` via `AsQueryable()`. By using `IQueryable` I make sure the queries stay optimised (in this case by Linq2Sql).

Though this is less then ideal and requires more manual code writing, I managed to get the design time data working again.